# Scalatest problem : value FunSuite is not a member of org.scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to write a test for my project in Scala 3. I added Scalatest library as :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
   ....
  "org.scalatest"           %% "scalatest"                  % "3.2.9"   % Test
)
```

I know my structure is right:

[image]

But it gives me error:

> value FunSuite is not a member of org.scalatest - did you mean scalatest.funsuite?
> [image]

However, I used the same in another project and it works fine.

Comment: I guess you need to import `org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite` and use it.

Comment: Thank you Johny! It works. But why all site example are based `org.scalatest.FunSuite`

Comment: No idea. But clicking the first mention of `FunSuite` in [Getting started with FunSuite](https://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite), does land you in scaladoc for [AnyFunSuite](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/funsuite/AnyFunSuite.html). But sample code from there on uses FunSuite.

Comment: If you answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I am guessing the issue is related to some bug in the way they update their documentation. Maybe you could raise an issue in their Github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Johney

The correct usage is as below (at least in scala 3.0.2):

```
import org.scalatest.funsuite.*

class TestParser extends AnyFunSuite {
}
```

Of course the tutorials such as [Getting started with FunSuite](https://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite) are based using `import org.scalatest.FunSuite` but the right examples is [here](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/funsuite/AnyFunSuite.html)  which also referred as a first mention of **FunSuite** in [Getting started with FunSuite](https://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite) .